# Batch file to verify existence of any files in folder and then present user a message

Tags: batch-file

I need to verify if any files exist in a folder and if so present the user with a message.

Currently I have this:

```
IF EXIST C:\PLUS\ADMIN\BATCH\*.* (
start "" cmd/c "echo Files in the directory! &echo (&pause
)
Exit
```

I've spent hours reading the things I've dug up on variables and piping results to things but I'm a complete batch file newbie so I'm really hoping someone can just tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Currently the batch file runs just fine but it's throwing up the message on the screen regardless of whether there are files in the directory or not.  Those files tend to be named 20141010.570, 20141011.571, etc. with variable file extensions based upon an ever increasing number (so it'll stretch into 4 digits once it's done with *.999)

Comment: Do all the files come from 2014 and so start with `2` ?

Comment: Yes, they will always start with the year as the beginning of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in windows all folders contain at least two folders (`.` and `..`) and the test `if exist c:\somewhere\*` will always be true.

One easy solution is to use `dir` command asking to only show the files, without directories,  and see if it raises an error

```
dir /a-d "C:\PLUS\ADMIN\BATCH\*" >nul 2>nul && (
   start "" cmd /c "@echo Files in the directory! &@echo(&@pause
) || ( 
   echo there are no files
)
```

The `/a-d` will exclude folders. If there are files, `errorlevel` is not set and the code after `&&` is executed. Else, if there are no files, dir command fails, errorlevel is set and the code after `||` is executed.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!  That solved it.  The only correction was I needed to insert a space between cmd and the /c otherwise it didn't work.  What a relief, i thought I was losing my mind with this!

Comment: @Mike, sorry, i typed it directly instead of try/copy/paste and missed the space. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %A in ('dir /b^|findstr /i /r "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]*') do echo %A
```

or

```
dir /b|findstr /i /r "\<[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9]*\>"&&Echo File Found||Echo File Not Found
```

The pattern is three or more numeric characters, a dot, then three or more numeric characters, ch. It must be the entire string (so a22222.222 won't match).

Type `findstr /?` for help. Dos's 6.22 Help files lists return codes as 0 found, 1 not found, and 2 error.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.


.
--
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the files start with 2014 then you can use this:

```
IF EXIST "C:\PLUS\ADMIN\BATCH\2*.*" (
   echo Files are in the directory!
   echo(
   pause
)
Exit
```