# What is the purpose of 2>nul in this Stack Overflow answer?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, output, stdout

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313753/4182398) contains the following code:

```
dir /a-d "C:\PLUS\ADMIN\BATCH\*" >nul 2>nul && (
    start "" cmd /c "@echo Files in the directory! &@echo(&@pause
) || ( 
    echo there are no files
)
```

The `>nul` is to redirect `stdout` to `nul`. What purpose does the `2>nul` serve, and in what situations is it needed?

Comment: This was not asked about so I'm posting a comment here. Start "" opens a second console window, running cmd /c which starts a new command interperter. There could be a closing quote " after ...@pause, but it's not needed. If running Windows, open a console window and enter help start for more info on start, and also help cmd for info on cmd.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard See the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: @Mofi Much appreciated.  Great article.  BTW, that article is listed under the *Command Line Reference for Windows XP*.  Does MS have a similar Command Line Reference for Windows 7?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Yes, there is a newer [Command-Line Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) for Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2000, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8. But it does not contain the article about the command redirection operators.

Comment: Thank you Mofi.  I thought I just wasn't finding the article.  Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard You might be also interested in SS64 article [Command redirections, Pipes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) from SS64 [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD  command line](http://ss64.com/nt/). The documentations on SS64 are ofter better because of taking all Windows versions into account.

Comment: @Mofi Fantastic.  Very useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of Windows console programs, 2> is stderr. It would be needed if the program being run might output text to stderr.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard `stderr` *is* a different stream. Try `dir nosuchfile.whatever >nul` at a cmd prompt and you'll still see the `stderr` output "*file not found*".

Comment: @dxiv Great example.  Thank you.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: Try this at the command prompt: `dir /B *.txt 2>Error.msg & findstr /N /A:4E "^" *.msg` and then change the `*.txt` by a not existing extension... **`;-)`**